# Vectorize calling numpy function on third dimension of array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array `data` where dimensions `a` and `b` represent the resolution of an image and `c` is the image/frame number. I want to call `np.histogram` on each pixel (`a` and `b` combination) across the `c` dimension, with an output array of dimension `(a, b, BINS)`. I've accomplished this task with a nested loop, but how can I vectorize this operation?

```
hists = np.zeros((a, b, BINS))
for row in range(a):
    for column in range(b):
        hists[row, column, :] = np.histogram(data[row, column, :], bins=BINS)[0]
```

I am confident that the solution is trivial, nonetheless all help is appreciated :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate histograms along axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152436/calculate-histograms-along-axis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.histogram` computes over the flattened array.
However, you could use `np.apply_along_axis`.

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda a: np.histogram(a, bins=BINS)[0], 2, data)
```

Comment: Note that while `np.apply_along_axis` is simple to use, it is generally not much faster than loops due to the pure-python lambda (that cannot be truly vectorized internally). In fact, is slightly slower on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting problem.

#### Make a Minimal Working Example (MWE)

It should be the main habit in asking questions on SO.

```
a, b, c = 2, 3, 4
data = np.random.randint(10, size=(a, b, c))
hists = np.zeros((a, b, c), dtype=int)
for row in range(a):
    for column in range(b):
        hists[row, column, :] = np.histogram(data[row, column, :], bins=c)[0]

data
>>> array([[[6, 4, 3, 3],
            [7, 3, 8, 0],
            [1, 5, 8, 0]],

           [[5, 5, 7, 8],
            [3, 2, 7, 8],
            [6, 8, 8, 0]]])
hists
>>> array([[[2, 1, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 0, 2],
            [2, 0, 1, 1]],

           [[2, 0, 1, 1],
            [2, 0, 0, 2],
            [1, 0, 0, 3]]])
```

#### Make it as simple as possible (but still working)

You can eliminate one loop and simplify it:

```
new_data = data.reshape(a*b, c)
new_hists = np.zeros((a*b, c), dtype=int)

for row in range(a*b):
    new_hists[row, :] = np.histogram(new_data[row, :], bins=c)[0]

new_hists
>>> array([[2, 1, 0, 1],
           [1, 1, 0, 2],
           [2, 0, 1, 1],
           [2, 0, 1, 1],
           [2, 0, 0, 2],
           [1, 0, 0, 3]])

new_data
>>> array([[6, 4, 3, 3],
           [7, 3, 8, 0],
           [1, 5, 8, 0],
           [5, 5, 7, 8],
           [3, 2, 7, 8],
           [6, 8, 8, 0]])
```

#### Can you find a similar problems and use keypoints of their solution?

In general, you can't vectorise something like that is being done in loop:

```
for row in array:
    some_operation(row)
```

Except the cases you can call another vectorised operation on flattened array and then move it back to the initial shape:

```
arr = array.ravel()
another_operation(arr)
out = arr.reshape(array.shape)
```

It looks you're fortunate with `np.histogram` because I'm pretty sure similar things [have been done before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62160417/3044825).

#### Final solution

```
new_data = data.reshape(a*b, c)
m, M = new_data.min(axis=1), new_data.max(axis=1)
bins = (c * (new_data - m[:, None]) // (M-m)[:, None])
out = np.zeros((a*b, c+1), dtype=int)
advanced_indexing = np.repeat(np.arange(a*b), c), bins.ravel()
np.add.at(out, advanced_indexing, 1)
out.reshape((a, b, -1))
>>> array([[[2, 1, 0, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
            [2, 0, 1, 0, 1]],

           [[2, 0, 1, 0, 1],
            [2, 0, 0, 1, 1],
            [1, 0, 0, 1, 2]]])
```

Note that it adds an extra bin in each histogram and puts max values in it but I hope it's not hard to fix if you need.