# Speed up by eliminating slightly complicated double loops in python (advance. Parallelization)

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

The process in the loop is to quantize the phase to find the entropy, which is currently a double loop, batch and channel.

It would be very helpful if you could just tell me how to solve the above question, but I would also be very happy if you could tell me how to parallelize using CPU or GPU that could further speed up the process.

I am willing to convert to numpy etc if you need.

Will appreciate any help. Thanks,

```
import torch
import time

QDIVNUM = 100 # q means quantization

def calc_entropy(latent):
    l_batch, l_ch, l_height, l_width  = latent.shape[0], latent.shape[1], latent.shape[2], latent.shape[3]

    qwidth = 2*torch.pi/QDIVNUM # for quantize phase
    qthres = torch.arange(0, 2*torch.pi+2*torch.pi/QDIVNUM, qwidth) - torch.pi #If QDIVNUM=4 then qthres=[-3.1416, -1.5708, 0, 1.5708, 3.1416])

    qboxprob = torch.zeros(l_batch, l_ch, QDIVNUM)
    sum_entropy = 0

    ###double loop###
    for i in range(l_batch):
        for j in range(l_ch):
            qboxnum = torch.zeros(QDIVNUM)
            loopc, one_entropy= 0, 0      

            # get phase 
            allphs = torch.angle(latent[i,j,:,:])

            while(loopc < QDIVNUM): 
                # The number of quantization ranges included in a given quantization range is put into the count qboxnum.
                qboxnum[loopc] = torch.count_nonzero(torch.logical_and(qthres[loopc] <= allphs, allphs < qthres[loopc+1]))
                loopc += 1
            # calc probability density distribution
            qboxprob[i][j] = qboxnum / (l_height*l_width)  

            # calc entropy
            for m in range(QDIVNUM):
                if not (qboxprob[i][j][m]==0):
                    one_entropy += -1 * qboxprob[i][j][m] * torch.log(qboxprob[i][j][m])
            sum_entropy = sum_entropy + one_entropy
    mean_entropy = sum_entropy / (l_batch * l_ch)
    return mean_entropy


start = time.time()
latent = torch.rand(2,16,32,32)+ 1j * torch.rand(2,16,32,32) # for advance: .to('cpu') or .to('cuda')
calc_entropy(latent) 
print(time.time()-start)
# 0.145s
```

Comment: Not your question but we can simplify the start to `l_batch, l_ch, l_height, l_width  = latent.shape`.

Comment: is it supposed to always return `0.0`?

Comment: Also, simply changing it to use numpy instead of PyTorch and line 8 to ```zeros((l_batch, l_ch, QDIVNUM))``` (note the extra brackets) speeds this up by a factor of 6

Comment: In this example, `latent` is always a real number, not a complex number, so `angle()` always returns 0 or pi. I assume these are intended to be complex numbers.

Comment: As Nick ODell said, the input latent is assumed to be a complex number, sorry. I have also modified the code in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am willing to convert to numpy etc if you need.

I am much more familiar with NumPy than I am with Torch, so that's what my answer will use. :)

I see the following optimization opportunities in your code:

- **Use histogram**

  In this code:

  ```
              while(loopc < QDIVNUM): 
                  # The number of quantization ranges included in a given quantization range is put into the count qboxnum.
                  qboxnum[loopc] = torch.count_nonzero(torch.logical_and(qthres[loopc] <= allphs, allphs < qthres[loopc+1]))
                  loopc += 1
  ```

  This loop is equivalent to `np.histogram(allphs, qthres)`. The `histogram()` function will also be much faster.
- **Conditional log**

  In this code:

  ```
              for m in range(QDIVNUM):
                  if not (qboxprob[i][j][m]==0):
                      one_entropy += -1 * qboxprob[i][j][m] * torch.log(qboxprob[i][j][m])
  ```

  I see that this checks for 0, and only evaluates the log if qboxprob is nonzero.

  This can be vectorized. See [numpy: Efficiently avoid 0s when taking log(matrix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752989/numpy-efficiently-avoid-0s-when-taking-logmatrix)
- **Misc vectorization**

  This code can be changed to compute angles for every member of latent:

  ```
  allphs = torch.angle(latent[i,j,:,:])
  ```

  If you change it to

  ```
  allphs = np.angle(latent)
  ```

  It will compute angles for every member of latent in one call.

  In this code:

  ```
  qboxprob[i][j] = qboxnum / (l_height*l_width)
  ```

  You can change qboxnum to an array, then do `qboxnum / (l_height*l_width)` to divide every element of qboxnum by the height and width.

  Etc.
- **Vectorized histogram**

  Profiling the new code, I notice it spends lots of time inside `np.histogram()`. This is because I need to call it once for every batch and every channel. Unfortunately, histogram does not accept any kind of axis argument to vectorize it.

  Fortunately, someone on SO has already written a vectorized version. See [Calculate histograms along axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152436/calculate-histograms-along-axis/44155607#44155607)

  I noticed that your histogram bins are equally spaced, so I slightly modified their version to find the bin number using division rather than using `np.searchsorted()`, which I found was slightly faster.

#### Code

```
import torch
import time
import numpy as np

latent = torch.complex(torch.rand(2,16,32,32) - 0.5, torch.rand(2,16,32,32) - 0.5)
QDIVNUM = 100


def hist_laxis_div(data, n_bins, lo, hi):
    # Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44155607/530160 plus modifications
    data2D = data.reshape(-1, data.shape[-1])
    # commented out for performance
    # assert lo <= np.min(data) <= np.max(data) <= hi
    all_range = hi - lo
    bin_width = all_range / (n_bins)
    data2D = (data2D - lo) / bin_width
    dtype = np.int16
    assert n_bins < np.iinfo(dtype).max, "Too many bins for datatype!"
    idx = data2D.astype(dtype)
    assert (idx >= 0).all()
    assert (idx < n_bins).all()

    # We need to use bincount to get bin based counts. To have unique IDs for
    # each row and not get confused by the ones from other rows, we need to 
    # offset each row by a scale (using row length for this).
    scaled_idx = n_bins*np.arange(data2D.shape[0])[:,None] + idx

    # Allocate array for longest possible counts so that we can reshape it
    limit = n_bins*data2D.shape[0]

    # Get the counts and reshape to multi-dim
    counts = np.bincount(scaled_idx.ravel(),minlength=limit+1)[:-1]
    counts.shape = data.shape[:-1] + (n_bins,)
    return counts


def calc_entropy(latent):
    l_batch, l_ch, l_height, l_width = latent.shape
    # Combine last two axes of latent array
    latent = latent.reshape(l_batch, l_ch, -1)

    allphs = np.angle(latent)
    qboxnum = hist_laxis_div(allphs, QDIVNUM, -np.pi, np.pi)
    qboxprob = qboxnum / (l_height * l_width)
    # Take log of qboxprob where qboxprob is not zero. If it is zero, output
    # zero as the probability. This is safe because in the next step, we multiply
    # by qboxprob, so if it was zero, the output should be zero anyway.
    logged = np.log(qboxprob, out=np.zeros_like(qboxprob), where=(qboxprob != 0))
    # Multiply each element of qboxprob by logged, and sum them up.
    sum_entropy = -1 * np.dot(qboxprob.flatten(), logged.flatten())
    mean_entropy = sum_entropy / (l_batch * l_ch)
    return mean_entropy


print(calc_entropy(latent))
```

#### Timings

```
Baseline (using torch)
215 ms ± 2.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
Baseline (with `import numpy as torch`)
38.4 ms ± 699 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
Optimized NumPy version
1.3 ms ± 12.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

#### Testing notes

I tested this and found it was equivalent to the original for a random complex tensor.

Comment: Thank you!!　Without "for" loop... I thought it could be done, but seeing the real-world examples really made me realise how amazing numpy is and how effective optimisation can be. Even the tricks you have installed were carefully introduced with bullet points, and it seems to be the best reference book for me right now. Thank you so much m(_ _)m